# Converting monthly data to quarterly format

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

My current data is in the following monthly format:

```
DATE         HPI_F_ARIMA 
1987-01-01     63.967000
1987-02-01     64.42600
1987-03-01     64.736000             ...
...             ...
...             ...
2021-12-01      236.078323
```

--------Code so far----------

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    usdata = pd.read_csv('arima_forecast.csv')
    usdata['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(usdata['DATE'])
    usdata.set_index('DATE', inplace = True)

print('monthly format')
print(usdata)
```

Question 1: How do I convert this so it's in the quarterly format whereby the
monthly values are averaged for the relevant months in a quarter and
Does the DATE column have the last date value of each quarter?
The end goal is to get data in the following format, save it to a dataframe and then save the dataframe to a CSV file.

```
DATE         HPI_F_ARIMA 
1987-03-31     64.37
1987-06-30     ...
1987-09-30     ...
...             ...
...             ...
2021-12-31      ...
```

Also, how do I attach the CSV file I am using?

Comment: You don’t need to attach the csv file, see [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (for future questions) and [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s exactly what [.resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) does, with `Q` for quarterly:

```
>>> usdata.resample('Q').mean()
            HPI_F_ARIMA
DATE                   
1987-03-31    64.376333
1987-06-30          NaN
1987-09-30          NaN
1987-12-31          NaN
1988-03-31          NaN
...                 ...
2020-12-31          NaN
2021-03-31          NaN
2021-06-30          NaN
2021-09-30          NaN
2021-12-31   236.078323

[140 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: You’re welcome @UBS, see also [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ok I added feedback (accepted response). Still a newbie in Python and StackOverflow. But trying to learn fast (I think).